# Выбрать правильно оформленные предложения с прямой речью

Tags: прямая-речь

В каких предложениях чужая речь оформлена правильно?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мой ответ: 1, 4, 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильно оформленные предложения: **1**, **3**, **4**.

Начнём с конца. **5-е предложение** должно быть оформлено так же, как 1-е (вместо тире двоеточие):

*Но тут я вспомнил: «А вёсла-то забыли взять!»*

**3-е предложение** верное:

*«Я уже взрослый, — **объявил** Коля и **пояснил**: — Через две недели четырнадцать будет».*

Это предложение построено по следующему принципу (см. [**здесь**](http://new.gramota.ru/biblio/readingroom/rules/164-znapr)):

> **Примечание 1**. Если в слова автора заключаются **два глагола со значением высказывания**, из которых **один относится к первой части** прямой речи, а **другой ко второй**, то после слов автора **ставится двоеточие и тире**, например:
>
> *– Идем, холодно, – **сказал** Макаров и угрюмо **спросил**: – Что молчишь?*

Comment: Подумал, что полезно было бы формы записи предложения 3 и предложения из примечания свести к единому виду: ввести кавычки в пример, да вижу, это невозможно.

Comment: Да, понятно, я тоже видел, что они не идентичны в плане оформления, но смысл у них в одном — в двух глаголах говорения.